# Titanium Mobile Select File

Tags: file, titanium-mobile

I need to get a dialog box to open, to select a file.

1. To save a file, I need the user to choose a filename to save to
2. To load a file, I need the user to select an existing file

I can not find any file dialog in the API. Is there a method to popup a file select dialog?

Comment: I want to open file chooser options in ios using titanium. How can we do it?

Answer (score 2):

*First: This would only work on android since iOS doesn't allow this. (Of course you can do this but on iOS this doesn't make sense since files cannot be accessed by other apps and there is no SD card).*

Unfortunately there is no File Dialog available in Titanium. You can check Appcelerators's market place for existing plugins or you try it on your own.

On Android you should be able to read the contents of SD card and display them in a tableview. All you need is [`Ti.Filesystem`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem) API. It allows reading and writing of files to SD card. But be careful: there were some changes in Android 4.1+ so that it seems not possible to share files with other apps since you can't make them globally readable. (It's not possible to share this File URL with an intent, i tried this. You need a ContentProvider for that, which is not easily to implement with Titanium since it requires native extensions.) But it may be possible that they are readable with another File Explorer.